# Listening to events on any Chrome html user tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to write an extension that connects to all Chrome tabs that are html (critically, leaving out any tabs hosting non-html content such as `chrome://extensions/` and other non-user tabs, as that would surely cause lots of internal errors if those special tabs aren't entirely excluded from handling by my business logic code). No need for a Chrome extension button.

I would then like to execute some code on any of those user html tabs:

1. When the user has clicked a hyperlink or button.
2. When navigation to a new url is about to begin (and get the target url)
3. After a new page has completed loading in any of the tabs (and get the url)

I am not sure which approach is currently best to use, for each of those above, and also am initially unable to get to the url. Currently, I'm trying a background tab (should I, really?). The trouble is I am unable to get to the url through the `tab` object with that approach ―

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    console.dir(tab);
});
```

It appears the `tab` object does not directly point at a url.

Regardless this pointwise issue, I wonder what might be the most robust approach for accomplishing the overall scenario described: getting notified of those events for all html user tabs, and getting the url in every case. In the official docs, a relevant sample is very much elusive to find.

Comment: Sounds like a job for classic DOM event listeners in a *content script*.

Comment: Your current problem: You appear to have not specified `tabs` in the `permissions` key in your *manifest.json*, which is necessary for you to get URL information.

Comment: This looks like a question which is an [XY problem](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=XY+problem). While what you describe requires a content script and a background script, the basic thing that you are trying to do: get information about when a page is going to navigate, or has navigated to a new URL is what the [`webNavigation`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) events are for (in your background script).

Comment: Note: `webNavigation` events fire when there is actual navigation, they do not fire when the URL is updated, but no navigation occurs. This can happen in single page sites which use AJAX to update the page contents without actually navigating to a new page. For that, you need `tabs.onUpdated`, in addition to `webNavigation`.